# Skills of the Shevatim

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, avot-patriarch-fathers, shevatim-12-tribes, genesis-bereishith

I recently read this story - 'Warrior Prophets' by Ben Tzion: [https://ben-tzion.com/warrior-prophets/#:~:text=A%20Biblical%20Fiction%20Novel%20based,chaos%20sweeping%20the%20ancient%20world](https://ben-tzion.com/warrior-prophets/#:%7E:text=A%20Biblical%20Fiction%20Novel%20based,chaos%20sweeping%20the%20ancient%20world).
(Highly recommend it and his other works, btw)

There's a bit in chapter 2 ('Inside the Walls of Jericho') that I'm curious about:
Most people will know of the midrashim that describe Naphtali as a swift runner (discussed here: [Superspeed of Naphtali](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83501/superspeed-of-naphtali))

However, in this story, the author takes this further and has it that 'Each of the twelve tribes has a special aspect that exhibits itself in each generation. Amongst each of the tribes there are people who have strongly inherited a trait of their Tribal ancestor.'
He then goes on to specify such as 'Judah’s Instinct, Naftali’s Speed, Simeon’s Courage, Yissachar’s Stamina', and further that the Patriarchs have their own traits that are more general and easy to develop: 'Abraham is Generosity and Jacob is Astuteness... and Isaac's Sight'.

Whilst I understand that it is essentially a biblical fiction novel and will thus have some artistic licence involved, does anyone know of any midrashim etc (beside's Jacob's listing of their attributes and destinies) that detail ANY of the other Shevatim (The Abraham and Isaac ones are pretty obvious) had a particular gift or talent equal to the way they talk about Naphtali's abilities as a fast runner?
I'm really just curious as to where the author might have gotten some of these ideas.

(No HebrewBooks sources unless you are willing to translate, please.)

Edit: Not asking for literary reviews or opinions, especially since the author is literally the former Chief Rabbi of Uruguay. If you don't like, don't read, but please also don't get smarmy about my taste in literature. I can go to GoodReads for that kind of judgement.

Comment: I would not read this work. You could read plenty of great fantasy fiction or historical fiction without mixing up your understanding of Judaism.

Comment: N.T 

Thankyou for that supremely unhelpful comment and judgement on what kind of literature I enjoy, as well as the bizarre assumption that I can't distinguish the fictional aspect of a book from its inspirational source (I acknowledged the artistic licence), as well as effectively demeaning the equally distinguishing writing abilities of the author (who is literally the former Chief Rabbi of Uruguay).

Comment: I'm not attacking your taste in literature or the  writing ability of the author, but the fact that you're here asking a question based on it seems to indicate some blurring of the lines.

Comment: I'm not implying any such blurring in my question. I'm asking if - Since we DO have a midrash concerning Naphtali's speed, as well as various commentary on other traits mentioned such as Abraham's generosity and of Isaac's blindness being a sort of allegory for a different type of insight - we also have writings about the other Shevatim that might have inspired the author's ideas here. I'm 'asking a question based on' those midrash and hoping for more. I'm not saying that we MUST have such things for him to have had the ideas, but I just want to know if anyone has heard of anything similar.